# Take "a" and "b" as being equal if they are the same in their first 4 decimal places in R

Tags: r, function

I was wondering how I could have R take any two objects such as "`a`" and "`b`" (**shown below**) as being equal **if they are EXACTLY the same in their first 4 decimal places**?

**P.S.** Thus, I'm asking how I could make a conditional command out of this question.

```
a = 1.234574789

b = 1.234565638
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see how to code a custom function:

```
> equal <- function(a, b, sig=4) { return (round(a,sig) == round(b,sig)) }
> equal(1.23456, 1.23457)
[1] TRUE
> equal(1.23456, 1.23557)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

We can check the first 6 places, with `substr`

```
substr(a, 1, 6)== substr(b, 1, 6)
```

Or with `sprintf`

```
sprintf("%0.4f", a) == sprintf("%0.4f", b)
#[1] TRUE
```

Can create a function with this

```
f1 <- function(v1, v2) {
        sprintf("%0.4f", v1) == sprintf("%0.4f", v2)
 }

f1(a, b)
#[1] TRUE

f1(1.2345, 1.2346)
#[1] FALSE
```

and if we need to `round`, then use `round`

```
round(a, 4)
#[1] 1.2346
round(b, 4)
#[1] 1.2346
```

Also, the last solution can be also compared

Comment: surely the `round` approach would fail if, say, we have `b = 1.23450`. then `round(a, 4) =  1.2346` but `round(b, 4) = 1.2345`

Comment: @stasg  I mentioned others approaches as well and that is the reason I didnt compare it,  but there is another answer which has only `round`

Comment: yes, indeed the two other approaches you present do not have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if `a` and `b` are nearly equal within a certain `tolerance`, you can use `all.equal`

```
a = 1.234574789
b = 1.234565638
a - b
#[1] 9.151e-06

all.equal(a, b, tolerance = 1e-4)
#[1] TRUE

all.equal(a, b, tolerance = 1e-5)
#[1] TRUE

all.equal(a, b, tolerance = 1e-6)
#[1] "Mean relative difference: 7.41226865e-06"
```

Comment: `all.equal(1.2345, 1.2346, tolerance = 1e-4)` is TRUE. User wants FALSE in this case.